# Cómo puedo conseguir extraer una propiedad de un objeto Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, objeto

necesito ayuda. Acabo de empezar a aprender Typescript.
Estoy haciendo un ejercicio y no consigo solucionar un problema.
Tengo una clase persona con interfaces(direccion, mail, telefono. Estas forman parte de persona y tienen más propiedades).
La cosa es que no consigo extraer el valor de "calle" que está almacenado en "direccion".

```
    function busquedaPersona(dni: string): Persona{
    const persona = personas.find(p => p.dni == dni );
    return persona as Persona;

}


const encontrarPersona: Persona = busquedaPersona("39954321G");


console.log(encontrarPersona.direccion['calle'])
```

La función busca a la persona que tenga ese DNI y una vez la tengo me gustaría acceder a calle para mostrar su valor por consola.
Pero haciendo eso, me muestra "undefined".
Si solo imprimo "direccion" entra correctamente el objeto.
¿Qué debo hacer? Gracias.

Comment: **Calle** es un valor de dirección o es una propiedad mas de dirección?

Comment: si te aparece `undefined` es que la propiedad `calle` no forma parte de `dirección`. Comprueba si deberías usar mayúsculas, por ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes [desestructurar](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) la propiedad `calle` por si estas escribiendo mal alguna propiedad como se ve en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
interface Persona {
  dni: string;
  direccion: {
    calle: string;
  };
}

function busquedaPersona(dni: string): Persona {
  const personas: Array<Persona> = [{
      dni: '39954321G',
      direccion: {
        calle: 'Emelie Park',
      },
    },
    {
      dni: '123DFS12D',
      direccion: {
        calle: 'Gutmann River',
      },
    },
  ];

  const persona: Persona = personas.find((p) => p.dni == dni);
  return persona;
}

const {
  direccion: {
    calle
  },
}: Persona = busquedaPersona('39954321G');

console.log(calle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta parte de tu codigo esta mal, no esta definido el nombre de tu constante

```
const {
  direccion: {
    calle
  },
}: Persona = busquedaPersona('39954321G');
```

Tiene que ser algo como esto:

```
const encontrarPersona: Persona = busquedaPersona("39954321G");
console.log(encontrarPersona.direccion['calle']);
```

Otra forma de acceder al atributo:

```
console.log(encontrarPersona.direccion.calle);
```

Tambien te recomiendo que crees otra interface para Dirección

```
interface Direccion {
    calle: string;
}

interface Persona {
    direccion: Direccion;
    mail: string;
    telefono: string;
    dni: string
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por el aporte pero eso de que no está definido la constante si está bien a eso se llama `Destructuring` si quieres saber más acerca de cómo se usa puedes verlo [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: muchas gracias, es la primera vez que veo algo como esto.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la aportación. He resuelto el problema y al final era que en la clase Persona llamaba a Direccion como una lista, lo he modificado y me deja acceder sin problema.